# Meaning of the expression "providing a spur for"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning the expression

```
Providing a spur for
```

?

Does it mean `encourage`? Also in this case what is the literal meaning of the noun `spur`?

Example:

> And just as group living promotes intelligence, so intelligence allows
>   larger groups to function, providing a spur for the evolution of yet
>   more intelligence.

Comment: As stated, it doesn't mean anything. Could you quote the complete sentence it came from?

Comment: Sorry, the expression I meant to ask the question about is `providing a spur for`. I put my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense is here

[American Heritage Dictionary "spur" (2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spur)

2. An incentive: *a spur to action.*

Note also definition 1, a device on a rider's boot used to urge a horse forward. This is the source of the metaphorical meaning.